# Jframe with canvas and Jpanel layout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm just beginning on making a GUI for a lwjgl engine.  I have a canvas on the left hand side and I want to have a JPanel on the right for previewing textures.  However as you can see, the image is barely visible. I've tried different Borderlayouts, trying to resize etc.. However I think I'm just doing something fundamentally wrong.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/iJtEkv6.png]

My panel class

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {
BufferedImage image;

public Panel(){
try {
    image = ImageIO.read(new         
File("C:/Users/tom/Desktop/raj/Jtest/src/AWT/house.png"));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
 // super.paint(g);

g.drawImage(image,0, 0, null);

}
```

and here is how I'm trying to implement it.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

     Panel panel = new Panel();
     UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("World Editor");
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

    button1.setSize(100, 100);
    button1.setLocation(600, 10);
   button1.setText("Test");
    canvas.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override

        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e)
        {  canvas.setSize(800, 600);

            newCanvasSize.set(canvas.getSize());
            }
     });



     frame.setBackground(Color.black);
     frame.add(button1);
     frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.EAST);
     frame.getContentPane().add(canvas,BorderLayout.CENTER);

     try {
        Display.setParent(canvas);
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1600, 1400));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Display.create();
        etc...
```

the setup should of been like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqMBb.png

```
      ePanel panel = new ePanel(0, 0);


      UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.jtattoo.plaf.hifi.HiFiLookAndFeel");
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("World Editor");

      frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     canvas = new Canvas();
     canvas.setSize(1200, 600);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     button1.setSize(100, 100);
     button1.setText("TEST");
     frame.add(button1);
     frame.add(canvas,BorderLayout.WEST);
     frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
     frame.pack();
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you already tried to set the image for a background label and resize it? Something like this:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Labelbackgroundiconalign.htm

Comment: My main issue is the layout,  the above code is everything that has anything to do with the gui.   I tried to position the jpanel with translate, resize, etc.  but for some reason the only way it ever gets displayed is if I set the borderlayout to East.  Otherwise one overlaps the other and which ever Frame.add call is last is the only one that gets displayed.

Comment: Oh and the Jbutton, I'm just playing around with that.  I can position is wherever.

Comment: Set to the JFrame a GridLayout.http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Canvas. That is an AWT class and you should not mix AWT components in a Swing application. I'm not sure what the point of the Canvas is, but you should probably be using a JPanel.

Don't call you class "Panel". There is an AWT class with that name already. Class names should be more descriptive.

In fact, don't even create a custom class. Just use a JLabel with an ImageIcon to display the image. I'm guessing the problem is that you didn't override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the "Panel" class so the size is (10, 10) by default which is the size the panel will have because you are using a FlowLayout. So either use a JLabel (easy solution) or implement the `getPreferredSize()` method to reflect the size of the image.

Comment: Ty, I new I was probably doing something like mixing things I shouldn't be.  The canvas is used to display my LWJGL display.  How else could I display my window without canvas?

Comment: Ah crud,  Display.setParent(canvas); is a lwjgl function that takes in a canvas argument .

Comment: I don't know anything about LWJGL, but you should learn the basics about Swing first before playing around with a game library. Displaying an image is a basic concept that is easily done with a JLabel and no need for LWJGL.

Answer (score 0):

Set a GridLayout to the JFrame new GridLayout(0, 2)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html
That way, the JFrame has left and right side. Then create and add two JPanels to the Jframe. Do not forget resize the panels and the frame.
After that, create a label, set to it an icon  image, resize it and add it to the right panel.